# how to copy files with certain suffix for a certain times?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Say I have a folder which have the file from "meta-00000" to "meta-10000". However, I only want to transfer files from "meta-00000" to "meta-00300"(301 files) into another directory, how should I do this? I am asking this because I don't want to type `cp ./meta-000xx ./directory` for 301 times! Is there any good solution?

Comment: Write the little shell script using for loop which would runs for 300 times.You can execute the shell script file.

Comment: But I don't know how to append the loop variable to the end of the file, could you please show me one example?

Answer (score 2):

This should work in almost any shell:

```
cp meta-00[0-2][0-9][0-9] meta-00300 directory
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cp meta-{00000..00300} directory     # Bash 4
```

or

```
for ((i = 0; i <= 300; ++i)); do
    cp meta-$(printf '%05d' $i) directory
done
```

Comment: A range specifier {00000..00300} is not available in many versions of `bash` or other shells.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `ls -1 meta-000* | head -n 301`
do
    cp $i target_directory/
done
```

or

```
for i in $(seq -f "%05g" 0 300)
do
    cp meta-$i target_directory/
done
```